# Trying to retrieve followers from a list of twitter accounts in R

Tags: r, twitter, api-design

I'm trying to get the followers of certain accounts with the twitteR package in R:

```
names_list <- c("USER1","USER2", "etc.")

twitter_account <- c()

for (i in names_list){

  url = paste("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=",names_list[i], sep = ',')
  twitter <- GET(url,sig)
  content = content(twitter)

  userz <- getUser(names_list[i])
  userz$getFollowers(names_list[i])

  }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work (getting an error, but even then I'm pretty sure it won't work. I'm relatively new to R so any help would be appreciated to pull this data. Even without the twitteR package.

```
[ Error in if (num <= 0) stop("num must be positive") else num <- as.integer(num) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed]
```

And it would be helpful if you could explain how this can be done with retrieving the names_list from a csv file actually. But that's not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem comes from the getUser line.

```
userz <- getUser(names_list[i])
```

In this case, 'i' is a value in names_list as you have initialized your for loop as

```
for (i in names_list){
```

Thus, your names_list[i] is equivalent to names_list['USER1'] and NOT to names_list[1].

I think what you want is either to iterate on names and refer directly to the name:

```
for (name in names_list){

  url = paste("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=", name, sep = ',')
  twitter <- GET(url,sig)
  content = content(twitter)

  userz <- getUser(name)
  userz$getFollowers(name)

  }
```

or to iterate over an index and use indexing of names_list:

```
for (i in 1:length(names_list)){

  url = paste("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=",names_list[i], sep = ',')
  twitter <- GET(url,sig)
  content = content(twitter)

  userz <- getUser(names_list[i])
  userz$getFollowers(names_list[i])

  }
```

Comment: seems to throw an error still:

 Error in if ((!is.null(num)) && (length(vals) >= num)) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning message:
In doCursorAPICall(paste(type, "ids", sep = "/"), "ids", num = n,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Can you tell us at which command is this error thrown? From what package is the GET function from? What does the sig stand for? Can you provide me with an complete example (eventually not in the for loop)? Also, I have edited the first loop as I hadn't seen the names_list[i] inside the url.